# Hello World in MVC6 troubleshooting

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble getting the latest MVC6 beta to display pages.  (Right now, it launches, but returns a blank page stub.)  My development machine is Win7 with VS2015.

I am getting this behavior with an existing MVC 6 app, a stock Visual Studio --> "Add New Project" --> "ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates" --> "Web Application", and even tried a clean version of [this boiler plate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6/).

What can I do to troubleshoot this?  These projects build and have no errors.  Identical behavior is seen using IIS Express and full IIS.

Are others experiencing this?

Comment: Are you getting an HTTP response? Is it hitting your controller method? What does Fiddler show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty broad question - here's some pointers to help you get started:

- Ensure you have the beta7 [tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738) installed.
- git checkout [aspnet/home](https://github.com/aspnet/home)
- Build and run `samples\1.0.0-beta7\HelloMvc`
- If you don't get any errors, drop to the command line in the directory above and try the same thing with dnx:

  - `dnvm list` - check that `1.0.0-beta7` is selected
  - `dnu restore`
  - `dnx web`

Comment: One big challenge is that the MS Download center seems to be broken for the beta 7 tools.  Clicking through your link, and hitting the download button, no files ever download.  I pulled down the github source, but I'm uncertain how to install them

Answer (score 0):

Using the tools that Stafford Williams provided, I marched through the various issues.
DNVM showed that the version was right, but it was set to x86 rather than x64. I fixed that, but

```
    dnvm use 1.0.0-beta7 -arch x64 -p
```

fails to save the architecture as default.  Apparently the -p switch is still buggy in this Beta

EDIT:  The below works to change the default.  I'm not actually certain which way is the "correct" way.
        dnvm alias 1.0.0-beta7 -arch x64

Once that was solved, I attempted a dnu restore, but it threw an exception that I traced back to the project.lock.json file in samples\1.0.0-beta7\HelloMvc, which I deleted and did a rebuild.  I then had a solution that built without errors.

At this point HelloMVC worked properly, but my code still produced nothing but an empty page when I tried to use my Controller.

The culprit was a bit of boilerplate that didn't work: my Controller class was decorated with an [Route("/(controller)")] attribute.  (I'm honestly not sure which version of boilerplate that was copied from.  Could've been an earlier beta, or some other sample code I had found.)  Commenting out that attribute finally brought peace and rainbows to the land, and things began working as expected.

Big thanks to Stafford Williams for his simple and well written troubleshooting tips.  It helped immensely on this adventure into the MVC Betas!